# Convert XML data to POJO with Jackson XML jar?

Tags: java, xml, jackson-dataformat-xml

Am work on java project with XML data from another web-service. Am new to Jackson framework. Create the POJO file but while mapping it show error like *Unrecognized* field column. Don't know how to map my response

**XML Response**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CellSet>
    <Row key="MNg==">
        <Cell column="ZG9ybWFudF9kZXRhaW29u" timestamp="1563189660088">MjAQ==</Cell>
        <Cell column="ZG9yxzOkV5ZXBsdXM=" timestamp="1563189660088">RI0</Cell>
        <Cell column="ZG9ybWFudF9kZWxzOl=" timestamp="1563189660088"/>
        <Cell column="ZG9ybaWxzOlVDSUM=" timestamp="1563189660088">Mg==</Cell>
        <Cell column="ZG9ybWFudF9kZXRhYXRl" timestamp="1563189660088">MMQ==</Cell>
        <Cell column="ZG9ybWxzOlpveWE=" timestamp="1563189660088"/>
        <Cell column="ZzOndhdGNoZXM=" timestamp="1563189660088"/>
    </Row>
</CellSet>
```

**CellSet Class**

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "CellSet")
public final class CellSet {

public CellSet() {}

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Row")
private Row[] rows;

public Row[] getRows() {
    return rows;
}

}
```

**Row Class**

```
public final class Row {

public Row() {}

@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Cell")
private Cell[] cells;

public Cell[] getCells() {
    return cells;
}

}
```

**Cell Class**

```
public final class Cell {

public Cell() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "column", isAttribute = true)
private String column;

@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "timestamp", isAttribute = true)
private String timestamp;

public String getColumn() {
    return column;
}

public String getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
}
}
```

Help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I dont know is this the same as JSON parsing, but i had to set @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true) annotation on my classes because there was some properties which I had no need to parse. See if there is some similar annotation for XML because  i think this 'Unrecognized field column' in your error code means that you are not parsing all attributes from response.
EDIT:
I found this: objectMapper.configure(DeserializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);   --Just add it on objectMapper

Answer (score 0):

First of all, looking at the xml document and the Java bean tree, I made the assumption that a response can have multiple `Row` elements under the `CellSet` root element.

So, given the above assumption, there are several problems with your object model. The first is the misuse of the `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`. This annotation signifies that an array of XML elements is wrapped by a higer-hierarchy element. so when you write

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "Row")
private Row[] rows;
```

jackson expects an input like this

```
<Row>  // xml wrapper
  <rows>  // xml array 
  <rows>
  <rows>
</Row>
```

in fact, you need to tell jackson that the row array is *unwrapped* like this

```
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
@JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Row")
private Row[] rows;
```

and same for cell array.

the other problem is that `Row` class does not have a target for key attribute and  `Cell` does not have a target for the text value of the cell element.
the complete solution is given below

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "CellSet")
public class CellSet {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Row")
    public Row[] rows;
}

public class Row {

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "key", isAttribute = true)
    public String key;

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "Cell")
    public Cell[] cells;
}

public class Cell {

    @JacksonXmlText()
    public String value;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "column", isAttribute = true)
    public String column;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "timestamp", isAttribute = true)
    public String timestamp;

}
```

last note: your classes are also missing setter methods (this is deserialization/unmarshalling, right?) in the above solution, all variables were made public for brevity